# How to specify number formats in Google's sankey charts / D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-visualization

I've become a big fan of Google's sankey charts, but one thing is bothering me - I can't figure out how to do number formatting so that the relevant units show up with the numbers in the third data table column. I've tried several approaches - trying to set 'pattern' options, using formatter, but for the life of me nothing seems to work - see this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nickdunbar/t9e3dcy3/1/

```
sankey: {
    iterations: 64,
    node: {
    pattern: '$### m', nodePadding: 30, interactivity: true, label: { fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                     fontSize: 14,
                     color: '#871b47',
                     bold: false,
                     italic: true } 
    },
    link: {
        pattern: '$###.## bn'
        },
```

Number formatting works so smoothly for the other Google chart types I can't believe that there isn't an option available somewhere. It isn't in the Google documentation. I have looked at the D3 literature but nothing obvious springs out there either.

Comment: Where exactly do you want them to show up? In the middle of the links or on either side? Because links might be rendered wildly entangled it will be difficult to position them avoiding any overlap.

Comment: In the middle of the links, where the mouseover tooltip currently shows the 'revenue' variable.

Comment: Ah, I think, I misunderstood that. I thought, you were looking for a way to print those values on the links itself. You are looking for a way to format the  tooltip, right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to better fit your needs. Have a look if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. But see my corollary question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [Customizing tooltip content](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-tooltip-content) for a way to achieve what you are looking for. You need to specify your custom tooltips' content as another column of your data:

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

By specifying a custom formatter according to your pattern

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'$###.## bn'});
```

you could then append the information by mapping the input:

```
data.addRows([
        ['Fred','Ann',107.91], 
        ['Bill','Ann',47.86],
        // more input...
    ].map(function(d) {
        d.push(formatter.format(d[2]);   // the tooltip's formatted content as last column
        return d; 
    }));
```

Using this mapping, you may apply every number format you are looking for, or do even more fancy stuff like [HTML formatting](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#using-html-tooltips).

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["sankey"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'$###.## bn'}); 
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    data.addRows([
        ['Fred','Ann',107.91],
  ['Bill','Ann',47.86],
  ['Carol','Ann',817.9],
  ['Jim','Kevin',400],
  ['Ann','Kevin',973.67],
  ['Sally','Kevin',146.47],
  ['Kevin','EVP Sales',1520.14]
        ].map(function(d) {
         d.push(formatter.formatValue(d[2]));
         return d; 
     }));
       

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
        formatNumber: '$### bn',
        sankey: {
  iterations: 64,
  node: {
  pattern: '$### bn', nodePadding: 30, interactivity: true, label: { fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                         fontSize: 14,
                         color: '#871b47',
                         bold: false,
                         italic: true } 
  },
  link: {
   //colorMode: 'source',
   pattern: '$### bn'
   },
 allowHtml: 'true',
 tooltip: {isHtml: 'true'}
   }

    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_multiple'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
</script>
<body>
    <div id="sankey_multiple" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: One corollary to the question would be how to do this if one was creating the data table by a different approach, for example using a loop based on a dashboard selection. In pseudo code:  for (var i = 0;i<rows; i++) {data.addRows([get some values]); }

Comment: The technique sketched in my answer is not restricted to the use of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This appeared to be just the best match for the given problem and may be replaced by any other means of iteration through the array like a `for` loop. The basic principle is to a) add another column containing the customized tooltips' content, and b) populate this with customized data. This won't necessarily require a `NumberFormat`, you could do any manipulations to your liking.

Comment: Indeed, and in my loop example, I worked out that you can achieve the same result by including 'formatter.formatValue(get data)' in the addRow line. One thing worth mentioning is that when you turn on custom tooltips, you kill the Google charts default tooltip which has 'source -> target' etc. If you want to reinstate that you have to write it manually.